# Improving NGINX Throughput on a Single SSL Thread

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, cpu-usage

We are configuring a file delivery server using nginx.  The server will be serving large files over HTTPS.

We have run into an issue where we can only achieve around 25MB/s on a single HTTPS thread.

We have tested using a non-HTTPS single download thread (http://) and can achieve full line speed (1Gb/s) at around 120MB/s.

CPU is not anywhere near max encrypting the transfers.  We have PLENTY of processing power spare.

We are using **aio threads** and **directio** for the file delivery system with large output buffers.

Here is an example of our config:

```
server {

sendfile off;
directio 512;
aio threads;
output_buffers 1 2m;

            server_name  downloads.oursite.com;
            listen       1.1.1.1:443 ssl;
            ssl_certificate /volume1/Backups/nginxserver/ourdownloads.cer;
            ssl_certificate_key /volume1/Backups/nginxserver/ourdownloads.key;
            ssl on;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            ssl_stapling on;
            ssl_stapling_verify on;
            resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
            resolver_timeout 10s;

location = / {
        rewrite ^ https://oursite.com/downloads.html permanent;
}


error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
                root /volume1/Backups/nginxserver/pages/;
                internal;
        }


location / {
                root   /volume1/downloads.oursite.com;
    limit_conn_status 429;
 limit_conn alpha 50;
}
}
```

Does anybody know how we can achieve faster transfer speeds for a single thread over an SSL connection?  What is causing this?  Thank you for your tips, suggestions, advice and help in advance.

Comment: Are you certain that you are CPU+SSL bound?  What throughput do you get without https?  Are you also seeing tcp retransmits in `netstat -s` or `nstat`

Comment: Please see our comment above.  We get full line speed on a single thread without HTTPS.  Also, look at our answer below - the openssl speed tests show the exact throughput we get on a single HTTPS thread.  If we double the threads we get double the throughput.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems our CPU is to blame.  No built-in AES encryption support.

```
admin@RackStation:/$ openssl speed -evp aes-128-cbc
Doing aes-128-cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 5462473 aes-128-cbc's in 2.97s
Doing aes-128-cbc for 3s on 64 size blocks: 1516211 aes-128-cbc's in 2.97s
Doing aes-128-cbc for 3s on 256 size blocks: 392944 aes-128-cbc's in 2.97s
Doing aes-128-cbc for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 98875 aes-128-cbc's in 2.98s
Doing aes-128-cbc for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 12479 aes-128-cbc's in 2.97s
OpenSSL 1.0.2o-fips  27 Mar 2018
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
options:bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) aes(partial) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes
aes-128-cbc      29427.46k    32672.56k    33869.92k    33975.84k    34420.19k
```